# Extract partial strings from a TextBox that replace the text of the same TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, substring

I need help with my code.
I have a TextBox which contains lines of text like this:

```
"hello my friends, how r u?","today is good"
"I'm fine","and you"
"have a nice day","thanks"
```

I want to remove sub-strings using `SubString()` (or another method, it doesn't matter) for this TextBox items.
I want to see this output in my TextBox (same TextBox, not a new) when I compile my code.

```
 hello my friends, how r u?
 I'm fine
 have a nice day
```

Comment: The C# tag is perfectly effective. You don't need C# in your question title (see tagging help for more information). Please can you include the code that you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the strings and removing the quotes should be enough, if there aren't any other quotes inside the text.
After splitting the strings, take the lines in the array that have an even index and put everything back in the TextBox.

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", textBox1.Text
                      .Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0)).Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: You welcome. Next time, you should post the code you have tried to solve the *problem* yourself. If it doesn't work, someone will fix it.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem but my code was so bad. Next time I will remember it and I will share. Thank you again.

Comment: If I want to apply this method a listbox with same code, is it work?

Comment: Yes, more or less. You can iterate the ListBox items (using `for`, not `foreach`). In the code, substitute the `.where()` part with just `.First()` and the `.Replace()` part with `.Trim('"')`. That's all.

Comment: " ((s, i) => i % 3 == 0)) " this part can't work sir.